# How can I find the most frequent two-column combination in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have my data in pandas data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,3,4,4,4], 'b':[2,3,4,4,5,5,5]})
```

So the dataframe looks like this:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
3  3  4
4  4  5
5  4  5
6  4  5
```

The column 'a','b' combination here are: 12(1), 23(1), 34(2), 45(3).
I am trying to select 4 and 5 and print them out because their combination has
most occurrences (3 times).

My code is:

```
counts = df.groupby(['a','b']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)
print(counts)
```

Output:

```
a  b
4  5    3
3  4    2
2  3    1
1  2    1
dtype: int64
```

But this only gives me a column [3,2,1,1]. This are the numbers combination counts.
How can I access elements 4 and 5 individually so I can print them out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Using `idxmax`, even the result is inorder, you still can find the index of max value

```
df.groupby(['a','b']).size().idxmax()
Out[15]: (4, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Wen. This is simpler!

Answer (score 2):

Pandas `GroupBy` objects are indexed by grouper key(s). In the case of multiple keys, this will mean a `MultiIndex`. You can just extract the first index of your result to give a `tuple` representing the most common combination:

```
counts.index[0]  # (4, 5)
```

Comment: Now I understand. This works perfectly. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest one to use mode in pandas DataFrame. It'll give a most frequent values across the rows or columns:

```
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
3  3  4
4  4  5
5  4  5
6  4  5

>>> df.mode()
   a  b
0  4  5
```

Comment: This is wrong. `mode` returns most often occurring value **individually** of all rows/columns as defined by axis. It doesn't return the most often occurring combination. It just so happens to be the same as the most often occurring combination in this example.